# Problema en GROUP_CONCAT () con subconsulta con CONCAT() con MYSQL

Tags: mysql, subconsultas, concat

Tengo las siguientes tablas en MYSQL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realizo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(estadoR),'-', NomEdo) AS X
FROM tabla c LEFT JOIN estados e ON c.estadoR = e.idEstado
WHERE campo LIKE '%xxx%' 
GROUP BY estadoR ORDER BY COUNT(estadoR) DESC
```

Me muestra estos resultados, hasta aquí todo bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero quiero que me los muestre en un campo así:

> 4-San Luis Potosí,3-Veracruz,1-Puebla

Estuve buscando como hacerlo y encontré que quizá con el GROUP_CONCAT() lo implemente de la siguiente manera pero no me da los resultados esperados.

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(estadoR),'-', NomEdo) 
FROM tabla c LEFT JOIN estados e ON c.estadoR = e.idEstado
WHERE campo LIKE '%xxx%') SEPARATOR ', ') AS conteo
FROM tabla c LEFT JOIN estados e ON c.estadoR = e.idEstado
```

Lo muestra así:

> 8-San Luis Potosí,8-San Luis Potosí,8-San Luis Potosí,8-San Luis Potosí,8-San Luis Potosí,8-San Luis Potosí,8-San Luis Potosí,8-San Luis Potosí

Espero alguien me puede ayudar, de antemano gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Para lo que necesitas requieres conocer algo de las bases de las queries complejas.

lo que te mostrare es algo llamado "SubQuery".

**Intenta esto**

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(T1.X) AS RESULTADO
FROM
(
SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(estadoR),'-', NomEdo) AS X
FROM tabla c LEFT JOIN estados e ON c.estadoR = e.idEstado
WHERE campo LIKE '%xxx%' 
GROUP BY estadoR ORDER BY COUNT(estadoR) DESC
) AS T1
```

Comment: Genial, justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias!